# Can the antiderivative of a function $f(x)$ be represented as $f^{(-1)}(x)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I was going over some common practices for solving ODE's today, and the following question came to mind:

Can we solve a "Differential Equation" of the form $\int {af(x)dx} + bf(x) = c$? I know it technically isn't  a D.E, but I don't know a better term for it.

That's when the notation of "$f^{-1}(x)$", the -1st derivative of $f$, and the first antiderivative of $f$.

With this notation, wouldn't one be able to apply the Laplace Transform and solve given some initial conditions?

Comment: It's called an integral equation. $f^{-1}$ has a pretty much universally established meaning as the inverse function, so using it for the antiderivative simply won't fly.

Comment: It is a DE; let $F(x)=\int f(x) dx$. Then you are trying to solve $\frac{dF}{dx}+\frac ab F=\frac cb$ which can be done via separation of variables.

Comment: If you use Euler's Operator notation for the derivative as $\DeclareMathOperator{D}{D} $ $f'=\D f$, then $\D^{-1}$ is the conventional notation for the antiderivative operator (and $\D^{-n}$, etc.)

Comment: You would need to fix the integration constant. In the Laplace setting that is usually not a problem as all functions are zero for negative times if not explicitly stated differently, but in general this introduces enough ambiguity that there is no heightened need for such a notation as $f^{(-1)}$ or $D^{-1}f$. But in principle, apart from the IC issue, there is nothing formally wrong about it.